# How can I write lua script or redis command to get all keys based on values?

Tags: redis, lua, jedis, lua-scripting-library

I have following structure in redis.

```
atp_sc:1111 "name" "tom1" "middleName" "jay1" "surName" "smith1" "age" "25"
atp_sc:2222 "name" "tom2" "middleName" "jay2" "surName" "smith2" "age" "28"
atp_sc:3333 "name" "tom3" "middleName" "jay3" "surName" "smith3" "age" "27"
```

atp_sc:1111
is my key and remaining all is my Map<String,String>. I am storing this structure from Java using jedis.
I want to get all the matching keys based on the name or middle name or based on the age. How can I do this in Java using jedis OR how can I write a lua script to get the expected results?

Comment: Did you check https://redisearch.io? it a redis extension that allows you to add such secondery index.

Comment: @GuyKorland is it open source extension?

Comment: Is under RSAL license, free for use unless you're a database (as defined in the license)